# Angularjs - how do i access directive attribute in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and i am stuck in accessing directive attributes in controller.

Directive

```
<rating max-stars="5" url="url.json"></rating>

app.directive('rating', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            maxStars: '=',
            url: '@'
        },

    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
     console.log(iAttrs.url); //works
}
```

controller

```
app.controller('ratingController', ['$scope', '$attrs' , '$http','$routeParams',function  ($scope,$attrs,$http,$routeParams) {


            console.log($attrs.url); //shows undefined

}]);
```

How do i access the url attribute in controller?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using ? How are you using `ratingController` and `$scope.rating` ? How about a fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: sorry,i updated the contoller. i just want to access the value of url attribute of directive in ratingcontroller

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to associate a controller with a directive, you can use the Directive Definition Object's `controller` property (either specifying the controller as a function or specifying the name of the controller (in which case it can be registered anywhere in your module)).

```
app.directive('rating', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            maxStars: '=',
            url: '@'
        },
        controller: 'ratingController'
    };
});

// Meanwhile, in some other file
app.controller('ratingController', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    // Access $attrs.url
    // Better yet, since you have put those values on the scope,
    // access them like this: $scope.url
    ...
});
```

---

When using two-way data-binding via `=`, the corresponding attribute's value should not be a literal (because you can't have two-way data-binding to a literal), but a string specifying the name of a property in the current scope.

Using `<rating max-stars="5"...` together with `scope: {maxStars: '='...` is wrong.
You hould either use `<rating max-stars="5"...` and `scope: {maxStars: '@'...`
or `<rating max-stars="someProp"...` and `scope: {maxStars: '='...` while the enclosing scope has a property named `someProp` with a numeric value (e.g. `$scope.someProp = 5;`).

Comment: yes i tried this, but when i console.log($scope.url) it shows undefined

Comment: @Arun: It could be due to several reasons (a simple typo, a timing issue (where the version of Angular plays a role, since some things have changed between version regarding when stuff is evaluated), misconfiguration etc). Please, provide a fiddle (or at the very least an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**).

Comment: I never knew this was possible until just now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){

  return{

    controller: function($scope,$attrs){
        console.dir($attrs);
    }

  }

});
```

That's it. If you want to access the elements attributes on a controller, you have to set up a controller for the directive.

(You could however, use a shared service to make those attributes available to another controller, if that's want you want to achieve)

Comment: ok,that makes sense. but if i have controller in separate file, how do i access from there? i did not downvote your answer

Comment: `controller` is an "injectable" function. The parameters are passed through DI (not potitionally), thus `element` and `attrs` will be undefined. A directive's `controller` function is **not** like the `linking` functions.

Comment: So you want to share your alements attributes with another controller? Is that controller asociated with a directive? Or is it used for a view?

Comment: @ExpertSystem is correct, I forgot to cut those out. You can, however, use the injectable $attrs

Comment: how do i link the external ratingController with the rating directive?so that i can access the directive atrributes in controller

Comment: In the code sample above, replace the function with `ratingController`

Comment: @Arun: It is really unclear what you are trying to achieve. Why don't you create a fiddle or plunkr demonstrating the problem, so we stop guessing and provide a "real" solutino instead :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/xapawoka/1/edit

Took your code and made a jsBin out of it. I can't see any problems whatsoever, so I'm assuming this is a simple typo somewhere in your code (could be the stray `[` bracket at the top of your directive definition).

Here's the code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ratingController', 
  function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  console.log('ctrl.scope', $scope.url);
  console.log('ctrl.attrs', $attrs.url);
});

app.directive('rating', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      maxStars: '=',
      url: '@'
    },
    controller: 'ratingController',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      console.log('dir.scope', scope.url);
      console.log('dir.attrs', attrs.url);
    }
  };   
});
```

And here's the output:

http://cl.ly/image/031V3W0u2L2w

Answer (score 0):

`ratingController` is not asociated with your directive. Thus, there is no element which can hold attributes bound to that controller.

If you need to access those attributes, the `link` function is what you need (as you already mentioned above)

What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: sorry, i updated the question. I want to access the value of url attribute in controller.